# Removing Legend ''fill box'' rectangle

Tags: r, plot, legend

```
par(mar=c(10.1,4.1,4.1,8.1), xpd =TRUE)
barplot(cp_ct2, beside = TRUE, col = c("darkblue","darkcyan"),las =2)

legend("topright",inset = c(-0.6,0), legend = c("Slight","Serious","",
                                            "Chi2: 226","P.Val:0.000"),
fill = c("darkblue","darkcyan"))
```

Effectively, this plot is producing 5 rectangular boxes in my legend. Where I only want two. When executing this code, the colours dark blue, darkcyan fill each box. I only need the factors ''slight''''serious'' filled and the chi-pvalue to be absent any rectangles.

Any ideas ?

Comment: is this what you want? `fill = c( "darkblue","darkcyan",NA, NA, NA), 
border= c( "darkblue","darkcyan", NA, NA, NA)` ps it may be worth adding the extra text using `text` rather than in the `legend`

Comment: Yes! Thank you.

Comment: @user20650  Could you write this up as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit objects from the legend by using `NA` instead of fills/colour etc

So for your example:

```
legend("topright", 
       legend = c("Slight","Serious","","Chi2: 226","P.Val:0.000"),
       fill = c( "darkblue","darkcyan",NA, NA, NA), 
       border= c( "darkblue","darkcyan", NA, NA, NA ))
```

In this case it may be better / easier to use a `text` function to add the extra statistics, rather than forcing it in to the legend.

A similar example,

```
par(xpd =TRUE)
cp_ct2 <- with(mtcars, table(vs, am))
X <- chisq.test(cp_ct2)

barplot(cp_ct2, beside = TRUE, col = c("darkblue","darkcyan"),las=1)

legend("topright", 
       legend = c("Slight","Serious"),
       fill = c( "darkblue","darkcyan"), 
       border= c( "darkblue","darkcyan"))

# add text to margin
mtext(side=1, line=3, substitute(chi^2==x~';'~~p==y, 
                                list(x=round(X$statistic, 2), y=round(X$p.value, 3))))
```